# CSS vertical divider between 2 columns that will match the longer column's height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and have been thinking about this problem for a few days.  The simplest approach was to set a `border-right` for the left column or a `border-left` for the right column with some padding to mimic a vertical divider.  The problem with such solution is it is not intelligent and so the height of it is always the height of 1 of the columns depending on whether `border-right` or `border-left` is used in the CSS.

I did some research and came across this: http://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ockht

It is very close to what I wish to achieve but I need some help in retrofitting the `.vertical-divider` into my Bootstrap 3 CSS framework and also making it responsive.

Here's the HTML I have now:

```
<section class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h4>Left column title</h4>
                <p>Left column text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Right column title</h4>
                <p>Right column text, which may be longer or shorter than the left column</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Anyone knows how this can be done?  Thanks!

Comment: Post what you have so far

Comment: @APAD1, I have updated my question.  Please have a look.  Thanks!

Comment: @topgun200204 make a note that width for example you are referring is fixed. if you are using bootstrap you need to consider this aspect. If you are using above example as reference and work out problem try this https://jsfiddle.net/z28h2ggc/ . test behavior with bootstrap.

Comment: Frankly, it's simpler to use the various options to just make the two columns the same height and use the border method. CSS Tables or Flexbox can do this.

Comment: @pratikwebdev, I am using Bootstrap and the width of both the left and right columns are responsive and therefore not fixed.

Comment: @Paulie_D, thanks for the suggestion.  What would be the best way to make the 2 columns the same height?  Another point to note is this structure of "left column" and "right column" is used on multiple pages of the website and they don't necessarily have the same height for the combination of "right and left columns" across the different pages.

Comment: As I mentioned, CSS Tables or Flexbox. There are several questions on SO on this.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D.  So I tried using CSS Tables and it worked well when my browser window is wide-open on my desktop.  Do you have any suggestion on how I can make the table responsive?  In my original Bootstrap grid approach, I had `.col-md-8` for my left column and `.col-md-4` for my right column.  Therefore the left and right columns will become a single stack when the Bootstrap media queries hits the "sm" size.  Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments.  After experimenting with a few different approaches.  In other to fulfill all my needs (listed below), I had to resort to a flexbox approach and it solves my original question nicely.  Thanks again!

Hopefully this information will be helpful for everyone!

Recap of my needs:

- Bootstrap 3 as backbone CSS framework
- Need a vertical divider between 2 Bootstrap responsive columns
- The vertical divider's height needs to match the longer column's height (which may be the left or the right column)
- The vertical divider will need to disappear when the Bootstrap responsive columns become a single column for mobile

**Final solution:**

HTML:

```
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-flex">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-flex-item vertical-divider">
            <h4>Left column title</h4>
            <p>Left column text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-flex-item">
            <h4>Right column title</h4>
            <p>Right column text, which may be longer or shorter than the left column</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.row-flex {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.col-flex-item {
display: flex;
flex-flow: column;
}
.vertical-divider {
border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: You may want to include your actual solution in the answer in order to help others who stumble upon this later.